# Load images using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to load 3 images from another page. This is my code

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var ids = ['#sk6x4', '#sk6x4a', '#sk6x4c'];
  var tabs = ['#tab1', '#tab2', '#tab3'];
  function getInfo() {
  $.each(ids, function (i, id) {
      $.ajax('/my-url', {
        success: function(data){
          var imgSrc = $(data).find(ids[i] + ' img').attr('src');
          $(tabs[i] + ' img').attr('src', imgSrc);
        }
      });
  });
  }
});
</script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active" id="tab1"><img src="" id="imageTriangle"/></li>
  <li id="tab2"><img src="" id="imageArc"/></li>
  <li id="tab3"><img src="" id="imageScat"/></li>
</ul>
```

This code works but wery slow. Images load very slowly. How i can make it faster? What is the right way to load images by ajax?

P.S. Images are optimized

Comment: Is the ajax call slow, or the image downloads? Maybe you need to optimize the images.

Comment: Images are optimized.

Comment: `.each` looping always makes the script slow try `for` loops

Comment: what is the cost of *loading* that other page (where the images live)? Is there some heavy server-side stuff going on to render that page? Maybe loading the images directly from their source location, rather than pulling them out of HTML, would be faster?

Comment: Where is getInfo called? With that snipplet it would take a really long time since it is never triggered. lol

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are making multiple ajax requests. It would be better to make just one, and return the URLs with JSON or something. Secondly, you don't even need ajax to load images. You can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var ids = ['#sk6x4', '#sk6x4a', '#sk6x4c'];
var tabs = ['#tab1', '#tab2', '#tab3'];
function getInfo() {
    $.ajax('/my-url', { // ajax call to get urls
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(ids, function (i, id) {

                var imgSrc = data.urls[i] //assuming that data is an array that contains the urls
                var img = $("<img /> ").attr('src', imgSrc).load(function () {
                    if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                        alert('Error...!');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(tabs[i]).html()
                    }
                });

            });
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Good point about not making multiple AJAX requests - but I don't think we can assume the OP's endpoint returns JSON data in an array. It seems to be a real *page load* returning an HTML document.